# Compile(decompile) to the single .java file

Tags: java, jar

Is that possible to compile whole project (or .jar) to a single .java file? There is no need for it to be nice and readable.

Comment: *"Is that possible to compile whole project (or .jar) to a single .java file?"*  What is the point of doing that?

Comment: That's not legal Java, unless the whole source is in one .java file.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There is some site, where I need to post single .java file.

Comment: *"some site"*  Gee.  Can you vague that up for me, it is in danger of containing information.  What is the URL of this site?

Comment: @duffymo that is the whole point, to move everything in one source file.

Comment: @desudesudesu, I get it.  Downvoting and voting to close.

Comment: Don't get those who closed it. How come that isn't a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single Java source file would impose the following limits:

- Using no (**`public`**) interfaces<sup>1</sup>.
- A requirement for no beans (which themselves must be a public class).
- A limit on the maximum size (Java class files have a size limit - around 65Kb per class file from memory).

> 1. @gustafc an interface doesn't have to be public.

So I'd say, generally no.

Comment: Are those interfaces used, when you de-compile .class files? .class have limit, but would .java compile to the single .class file?

Comment: I don't understand the first question.  A single Java file would compile down to as many classes as were declared in the source file.

Comment: let's say, I use http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui on some package, that used interfaces. Would it decompile back to interfaces?

Comment: I would presume so, but have never used decompilers, let alone that one.

Comment: I've decompiled interface. Yes, it decompiles in interface. Still don't get №1 limit: http://ideone.com/SWODzP

Comment: I did not follow the link.  Summarize it.  An interface must be public.  Only one public class is allowed per source file.  So if a source file has an interface in it, it is not going to contain any class that can do something *useful* with the interface.

Comment: @AndrewThompson an interface doesn't have to be public. `echo 'interface I{}class C{public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println("It works!");}}' > I.java && javac I.java && java C` works fine.